# Chrome extension: access to iFrame with a different domain

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, cross-domain, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm creating a basic Chrome extension that should apply some CSS styles to a specific website. In my manifest file I've added this domain. In some cases targeted website has an iframe with a different domain that I can't access it's content.

As I went throught the docs for Chrome developers, I've found two possible solutions:

1. Add "all_frames: true" option to the manifest.
2. Add domain of the iframe to the manifest.

None of this options helped me. I know that there are security limitations the restrict the cross-domain access. Is this the case or there is some way for the extension to access the iframes' content?

Currently my manifest file has this options:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "all_frames": true,
      "matches": [
        "https://*.domain1.com/*",
        "https://prefix.domain2.com/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "contentScript.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: The declaration is correct and it already runs an instance of the script inside the iframe, so you can access it directly via `document` without using the iframe element. You can check location.hostname and/or `window==top` to differentiate it from the main page and apply changes conditionally.

Comment: My problem was that I still tried to access the iframe's content instead of doing it directly via the ```document```.  Thank you for pointing it out!